# To test sorted items(High to Low price) are displayed properly using selenium webdriver

Tags: java, selenium, selenium-webdriver, testing, automated-tests

Here is the website I have to test:
http://tutorialsninja.com/demo/index.php?route=product/category&path=18&sort=p.price&order=DESC

the prices are sorted from highest to lowest. and I have to Check that sorting works correctly.

First problem is that i can't find the right selector (I only need the main price)

Here i have some code:

```
// scrape price elements
List<WebElement> price = driver.findElements(By.xpath(*--DONT HAVE THE SELECTOR--*));

// extract the prices from the price elements and store in a List
List<String> prices = new ArrayList<String>();
for (WebElement e : price)
{
    prices.add(e.getText());
}

// make a copy of the list
List<String> sortedPrices = new ArrayList<String>(prices);

// sort the list
Collections.sort(sortedPrices);

// true if the prices are sorted
System.out.println(sortedPrices.equals(prices));

assertEquals(prices, sortedPrices);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try this css, `div.caption p.price`  :

```
List<WebElement> price = driver.findElements(By.cssSelector("div.caption p.price"));
```

and print the values like this :

```
List<WebElement> price = driver.findElements(By.cssSelector("div.caption p.price"));
for(WebElement  e : price){
    System.out.println(e.getText().split("\\$")[1].split("\\.")[0].replace(",", ""));
    prices.add(e.getText().split("\\$")[1].split("\\.")[0].replace(",", ""));
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

**Try the below code.**

`xPath` for the prices of all items,

> //div[@id='content']//p[@class='price']//span

```
List<WebElement> price = driver.findElements(By.xpath("//div[@id='content']//p[@class='price']//span"));

/* extract the prices from the price elements and store in a List */
List<String> prices = new ArrayList<String>();
for (WebElement e : price)
{
    prices.add(e.getText());
}

/* make a copy of the list */
List<String> sortedPrices = new ArrayList<String>(prices);

/* sort the list */
Collections.sort(sortedPrices);

/* true if the prices are sorted */
System.out.println(sortedPrices.equals(prices));

assertEquals(prices, sortedPrices);
```

Answer (score 0):

I would go for below code: (In Python)

```
driver.implicitly_wait(10)
driver.get("http://tutorialsninja.com/demo/index.php?route=product/category&path=18&sort=p.price&order=DESC")
price = driver.find_elements_by_class_name("price")
pricelist = []
for p in price:
    pri = p.text.split('\n')[0].split('.')[0].replace('$','').replace(',', '')
    pricelist.append(int(pri))
print(pricelist)
```

Output:

```
[2000, 1202, 1202, 602, 122]
```

Comment: This is not Java